# JFrog artifactory 7.4.3 integration with mssql issue

Tags: artifactory, mssql-jdbc

I have installed the JFrog Artifactory OSS 7.4.3 on windows.It is working fine with default DB **Derby**.

Tried to integrate with MSSQL server. Configured DB url, username and password properly. when I start the service, it created the required tables in the database.

But application is throwing error in **artifactory-service.log** file as **The DB driver for mssql was not found. Copy the relevant DB driver to '$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib'.**

I have downloaded different versions of mssql jdbc drivers supported for jdk11. still facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you copied the library to the bootstrap folder `$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib` and it is still giving this error?

Comment: i have downloaded jdbc driver from the follwoing location and copied the jar to "$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib".  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58505

Comment: Yes, except, the documentation appears to be wrong! I needed to drop it into `$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib`, where all the other SQL JAR libraries are located.

Answer (score 0):

JFrog's documentation is wrong! Following their documentation (on Windows), Artifactory was unable to connect to SQL server when placing the MSSql JDBC driver inter `$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib`.

So I went sleuthing and found where they put all the other SQL server dialect libraries: `$JF_PRODUCT_HOME/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib`. Copy the MSSQL JDBC JAR file there and you'll be good to go!